# c# SSIS using same code for script task or script component: FireInformation

Tags: c#, error-handling, ssis

I'd like to be able to use the same code for a script task and script component (eventually creating my own reference library, etc).  I'm trying to keep things consistent and not have to have two versions of code.

My problem comes in when I want to firewarning or fireinformation or fireerror.

I'd like to do something like this:

```
public void fireInfo(object debugObj, string component, string message) {
    bool fireAagain=true;
    if (debugObj.GetType().ToString() == "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.EventsObjectWrapper")
        ((Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.EventsObjectWrapper)debugObj).FireInformation(0, component, message, "", 0, ref fireAgain);
    else if (debugObj.GetType().ToString() == "IDTSComponentMetaData100")
        ((IDTSComponentMetaData100)debugObj).FireInformation(0, component, message, 0, ref fireAgain);
}
```

But of course I get type or namespace could not be found errors.  Any thoughts of how to handle this better?

Comment: There are several drawbacks to script tasks and script components: 1) references have to be in the GAC (this is why your ref. can't be found, and  2) hard to debug.  I recommend using the Execute Process control to shell out to a c# console app.

Comment: Sorry if I wasnt clear.  The namespace I want to use is the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.EventsObjectWrapper which is valid in a DTS / script task and IDTSComponentMetaData100 which is valid in a script component.